# javascript: cancel all kinds of requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, httprequest

My website makes a lot of requests. I often need to cancel all current requests, so that the browser is not blocking relevant new requests.

I have 3 kinds of requests:

- Ajax
- inserted script-tags (which do JSONP-Communication)
- inserted image-tags (which cause the browser to request data from various servers)

For Ajax its no problem as the XMLHttpRequest object supports canceling.
What I need is a way to make any browser stop loading resources, from DOM-Objects.

Looks like simply removing an object (eg. an image-tag) from the DOM only helps avoiding an request, if the request is not already running.

**UPDATE:** a way to cancel all requests, which are irrelevant, instead of really any request would be perfect.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`window.stop()` should cancel any pending image or script requests.

Answer (score 2):

I think `document.close()` stops all requests, but I'm not so sure about it.