# how to cancel http request using javascript

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, dom, request-cancelling

i have a page on which there an event handler attached to an `onclick` event. when the event fires it passes contents of a textbox to a `GET` request. since **the url is not in the same domain** so i create a script tag and and attach the url to its source like this

```
elem.onclick=fire;

function fire()
{
var text=document.getElementById('text').value;
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.className="temp";
script.src="some url"+"?param="+text;
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

now if that event is fired and more than one time i want to cancel all the previous `GET` request(because they still might be receiving response) and make the `GET` request with latest text. But for this i need to cancel the previous requests. 
i tried

```
document.body.removeChild(script);
script.src=null;
```

**but this does not work in `Firefox`(i am using `Firefox 5`) although this works in `Google Chrome`**.Does anyone know if these requests can be cancelled in Firefox and if yes then how?

---

**UPDATE**
As suggested by Alfred, i used `window.stop` to cancel a request but does not cancel a request but hangs it up. It means that when i look into firebug it looks like the request is being made but there is no response.

Comment: Would you consider using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com)?

Comment: @Matt Ball i certainly would. but can u also suggest plain javascript bcoz i want to understand how its done?

Comment: I did a search on stackoveflow.com and found the [following answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117551/javascript-cancel-all-kinds-of-requests/117628#117628

Comment: @Alfred hey thanks a lot but u knw when i checked in firefug's net panel the request seems to have hung up and not cancelled actually and i cannot make any other requests too

Comment: @Alfred can i cancel a particular hung up request?

Comment: @lovesh okay :). P.S: JQuery can also stop requests(I believe even/also JSON-p / script tags). Maybe you should inspect JQuery source-code to see how they do this => http://pastebin.com/VSKPDCbh

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simple: for creating HTTP requests, use `<img>` instead of `<script>` element. Also you always have to change the `src` attribute of the **same** element.

```
var img;
function fire()
{
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var im = img || (img = new Image());
    im.src = "url"+"?param="+text;
}
```

You may ascertain that it actually works by doing the following: the URL you request should have a huge response time (you can ensure this using e.g. PHP's `sleep` function). Then, open Net tab in Firebug. If you click the button multiple times, you'll see that all incomplete requests are aborted.

Comment: and how do i cancel the request?

Comment: @lovesh The incomplete requests are automatically canceled if you create another request. If you would like to cancel requests and not to create another one, you can do this by setting `img.src = '';`.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely shooting from the hip, but if the script tag has not finished loading you can probably simply `script.parentElement.removeChild( script )`. That is more or less what mootools does anyway. (Technically, they replace `/\s+/` with `' '` first, but that does not seem to be terribly important).

Comment: this means that the HTTP request is not cancelled?

Comment: It should be the equivalent of `XMLHttpRequest.abort();` but no guarantees, I've never actually done that before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seems like a similar issue:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t506018-how-to-cancel-http-request-from-javascript.html

Comment: i m doing this all client-side. couldnt find anything helpful in that

Comment: Despite the title of the linked article, it is really about getting postback to an ASP.NET server to work, and is intimately involved with details specific to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be ok for you to use a JS framework? If so, MooTools has this functionality built into its [Request.JSONP](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP) object

Comment: i dont mind using a framework but i wud like to know how its done. can u explain or give a link that explains

Comment: can u explain how its done? i saw the link and i know that this can be done in javascript +1

Comment: Looking through the source code for it, it appears to be just removing the script tag from the DOM and setting the script variable to null. Maybe this last step is what you're missing since perhaps the request doesn't get cancelled as long as there is a reference to it. Not sure about this, though.

Comment: i tried it but doesnt work. i can see in firebug requests still being processed

Answer (score 0):

To get around the cross-domain issue, you might be able to use CORS instead (assuming you can change what's on the server):
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

If you do this, you could then use the more standard XMLHttpRequest's abort() function.

CORS is compatible with all the major modern browsers except Opera (http://caniuse.com/cors).