# dissecting mootools

Tags: javascript, jsonp, mootools-more

i had a problem and solving which required a functionality built in `mootools`. so i began dissecting it.
there a function a am interested in 
**`IframeShim.destroy`**
its like this

```
destroy: function(){
        if (this.shim) this.shim.destroy();
        return this;
    }
```

now what i cant understand in this what is `shim`.
Paricularly what i am trying to understand is 
**`Request.JSONP.cancel`**
its code is like this

```
cancel: function(){
        if (this.running) this.clear().fireEvent('cancel');
        return this;
    }
```

now this cancel calls `clear` whose code is like this

```
clear: function(){
        this.running = false;
        if (this.script){
            this.script.destroy();
            this.script = null;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

now in this clear function i can see `destroy()` which takes me to `shim`(see code at the top) and i m stuck.
All these functions are in [mootools-more.js](http://mootools.net/nightly/build/mootools-more.js)

Help?

it would be great if somebody could provide a plain javascript implementation of **`Request.JSONP.cancel`**
Does it have a `JQuery` alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destroy that is being called by the `Request.JSONP.clear` method isn't `IframeShim.destory`, it's part of the mootools core. Here's the source:

```
destroy: function(){
    var children = clean(this).getElementsByTagName('*');
    Array.each(children, clean);
    Element.dispose(this);
    return null;
},
```

All that `Element.dispose` does is call the native jasvascript DOM method [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) which deletes an element from the DOM.

So all JSONP.cancel is doing is seeing if a script DOM node was added via `Request.JSONP.cancel`. If it was, it removes the script element from from the DOM via removeChild.

The important thing is that it set the `running` flag to false. If you look at `Request.JSONP.success`, the first thing it does before calling your callback function is check if the `running` flag is set to false, and if it is, it returns immediately. This effectively "cancels" the execution.

If you meant does it cancel the HTTP request, the answer is no, it does not.

Comment: thanks,+1. does calling `destroy()`on a node cancels the any http requests made by the node.if u dont understand what i mean please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865574/how-to-cancel-http-request-using-javascript)

Comment: does that mean that `Request.JSONP.cancel` cannot cancel a HTTP request?

Comment: @lovesh no it does not cancel the HTTP request. What it does is it cancels the callback from executing once the script is loaded.

Comment: @lovesh notice in `Request.JSONP.send` they set the src to be the URL passed in the options + `callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_'+ index`. This links it to a mapped `Request.JSONP.success` which, before executing, first checks if this.running is false, and if it is, returns immediately and thus "cancels" it (since the assigned callback will never execute).