# HTML limit image downloads at the same time

Tags: html, image

I'm looking for best solution to throttle image download in SPA application.

Problem:

On slow network, when entering details page there's a lot of image downloads happening that are maxing-out browser connections, which breaks(makes unresponsive) UI that requires connections to do AJAX request on button clicks.

I'm looking for some HTTP/browser API to throttle image downloads at given time. Do you know is something like this exists?

Other approach I would like to have is ability to kill all GET request on button click (that could also solve this issue).

I cannot find such APIs. Maybe inserting these images as 'prefetch' could be good idea?

Or I have to "lazy" load these images as `<img data-src="url">` and then put them to custom fetcher that does up to 3 request at the time?

EDIT: found some related issues:

- [javascript: cancel all kinds of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117551/javascript-cancel-all-kinds-of-requests)
- [How do I abort image <img> load requests without using window.stop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929662/how-do-i-abort-image-img-load-requests-without-using-window-stop)

Answer (score 1):

1. Best is using a Lazy loading Module/Library of your SPA Framework . For example this library for React seems to be widely used: https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload. **I would defenitely use this approach.**
2. Build an lazy image loader yourself. Insert a placeholder image (or low quality image) that you then replace with the final image.
3. Yes. Parallel downloads per Domain are limited. But you can create a second Domain (=Subdomain) where you host your images so this can effectively increase the amount of parallel downloads. (But of course not the total bandwith).
4. Preloading: Just as a note: If you have a large app with lots of navigations paths/screens, it might be a waste of ressources if you download images of pages (or section of the page) the user then will not visit...  I would not rather do this, as mobile traffic is quite costly!
5. Have a look at the "importance" Attribute of an img Tag: importance 
   Indicates the relative download importance of the resource. Maybe this helps? But never used this before...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

```
importance 
Indicates the relative download importance of the resource. Priority hints allow the values:
auto: no preference. The browser may use its own heuristics to prioritize the image.

high: the image is of high priority.

low: the image is of low priority.
```

Comment: No SPA framework - I'm just using React for rendering.

Comment: I updates the answer. There seem to be very good React Libraries, here is a tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-optimize-react-applications-with-lazy-loading-232183e02768/ (The interesting part about lazy loading starts in the middle of the article)